# How can I print square of the numbers in full tringle (not left and right tringle) pattern in Python?

Tags: python

Hi I got a problem with a nested loop where the output must be like this:

```
 Required pattern

     1
    4  9
  16 25 36
49 64 81 100
```

Need exactly the same result

Comment: Please show your code and someone will undoubtedly tell you where you're going wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
def square_pyramid(n):
    number = 1    
    k=n*2
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,k):
            print(end= " ") #this sets spaces before each number
        k = k-2       #reduce space in front of every number, decreases row wise          
        for j in range(0,i+1):
            print(number*number, " ",end=" ")
            number += 1        
        print("\r")    #new line        
square_pyramid(4)
```